# jquery custom controlled scrolling navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to create a jquery-menu for my website so when you click in a menu item it will slide vertically to a target div (only div not whole page) in fixed 400*400 div

please suggest if there is any good plug-in available

eg.

left div- 
home
about
contact

right div-(needed to scroll according to click on the menu ) 
home container : visible
about container : hide
contact container :hide

Answer (score 0):

I used this once:

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html

Maybe it can help you.

Comment: it slides the whole page not particular div.